# RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8 )

Tags: github, git-bash, git-filter-branch

Please help me I just tried, and when I try to pull it shows everything is okay. On the other branch, I can pull but when I try this it shows this

```
git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 74, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (74/74), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
error: 6367 bytes of body are still expected 232.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```